# Modify module with plugins when Typescript definition split across multiple files

Tags: typescript, plugins, typescript-typings

In Typescript 2.2 I'm trying to define a module (HapiJS) which has various plugin options.

I refactored the core code into multiple .d.ts files and then imported and re-exported them all from the index.d.ts using the following pattern ([as seen here](https://github.com/AJamesPhillips/DefinitelyTyped/blob/7cbe95badb58151ca8ab3b0bec0ce2ea23fa72b4/types/hapi/index.d.ts)):

```
export * from './hapi/connection';
export * from './hapi/reply';
export * from './hapi/request';
export * from './hapi/response';
export * from './hapi/route';
export * from './hapi/server_views';
export * from './hapi/server';
```

In a separate module, it extends them [as seen here](https://github.com/AJamesPhillips/DefinitelyTyped/blob/9ed0009123299b9236515e76e9aa3618a365f405/types/inert/index.d.ts):

```
import * as hapi from 'hapi';

declare module 'hapi' {
    interface IFileHandler {
        /** path - a path string or function as described above (required). */
        path: string | IRequestHandler<string>;
        ...
    }

    // Extending hapi core:
    interface IRouteConfiguration {
        file?: string | IRequestHandler<string> | IFileHandler;
```

However when I did this all references to `IRequestHandler` above error with: "Cannot find name 'IRequestHandler'.".  If all the hapi code is moved back into one giant index.d.ts then it works as expected.  Is there a way to achieve this using multiple hapi definition files?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it out but perhaps it might be possible to use something like the following (though I doubt the `interface hapi.IRouteConfiguration {` will be acceptable):

```
import * as hapi from 'hapi';

declare module 'hapi' {
    interface IFileHandler {
        /** path - a path string or function as described above (required). */
        path: string | hapi.IRequestHandler<string>;
        ...
    }

    // Extending hapi core:
    interface hapi.IRouteConfiguration {
        file?: string | hapi.IRequestHandler<string> | IFileHandler;';
```

Alternatively perhaps importing from `hapi/server`, or whichever part is needed.